# How to make admob and mapbox compatible in unity?

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, admob, mapbox

SOME INFO:

- Unity 2019.4.40f1
- Mapbox Unity SDK 2.0.1
- Admob Unity SDK 5.4.0

Im doing something like Pokemon GO, everything works well but when admob is added i can not export it btw everything works right in editor. I made another empty project and i added Admob SDK to check if this version of Admob works with this Unity version, it works but when i added mapbox to it i have the same errors.

1.

```
> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 4 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :launcher:signingConfigWriterRelease
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
57 actionable tasks: 57 executed

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
```

2. 

```
> Note: D:\Monkey GO\Monkey Go
> 2.0.1\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> 
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> > 1 exception was raised by workers:   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class
> android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules
> classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar
> (:support-compat-25.1.0:)   Duplicate class
> android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules
> classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar
> (:support-compat-25.1.0:)   Duplicate class
> android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in
> modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar
> (:support-compat-25.1.0:)   Duplicate class
> android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar
> (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in
> modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar
> (:support-compat-25.1.0:)   Duplicate class
> android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules
> classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar
> (:support-compat-25.1.0:)   Duplicate class
> android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar
> (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in
> modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar
> (:support-compat-25.1.0:)   Duplicate class
> android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules
> classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar
> (:support-compat-25.1.0:)   Duplicate class
> android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules
> classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar
> (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
>      Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency
> resolution errors</a>.
> 
> 
> * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> 
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> 
> BUILD FAILED in 48s Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
> 
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
```

3. 

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
F:/_Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.40f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "F:\_Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.40f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
Note: D:\Monkey GO\Monkey Go 2.0.1\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.2.0:) and classes.jar (:support-compat-25.1.0:)
  
  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 48s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 4 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJar
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :launcher:signingConfigWriterRelease
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
57 actionable tasks: 57 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <dd2e71f8d45046b88d6d3169a8084aec>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <7105be432fb64891b07085914e6cd5c1>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: It looks like you have duplicate and incompatible dependencies. The External Dependency Manager may help with this. You want to select the option to update to AndroidX dependencies or it may be called Jetify.

Comment: I added these three lines to Gardle Properties:
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableR8=true
Now the error is much shorter do you know what can i do?
Please check it: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dfd2ZZyE29rwkGJGncz362k62jxUpVBzCi8zw6QgkXQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @RetiredNinja I belive in you :)

Comment: That error is problematic. You might try updating both of the plugins to the latest version hoping they've updated their dependencies.